# How to configure Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 on 64 bit windows 7 machine so it can connect to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 that I use from SQL Server Reporting Services 2012. My machine has 64 bit Windows 7. I am able to use report builder fine when I connect to SQL Server DB. Now I want to connect to a MySQL DB (version 5.1.73).

**What I have done so far:**

1) I have installed 32-bit version of "MySQL ODBC Connector Unicode 5.3.8". I have installed 32-bit version as the Report Builder is a 32 bit application and so needs 32-bit version.

2) Then I have added entry for the MySQL DB in the "System DSN" by selecting the "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver" that i had installed. As my machine is 64 bit, I have added this entry in "System DSN" of "ODBC Data Source Administrator" located at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

3) Then from report builder I am trying to create new Data Set and a new data source connection to this data set. I am selecting connection type as "ODBC" and click on "Build".
[image]

4) In "Connection Properties" window I select "Use user or system data source name:" and picking the DSN name that I have added in the "System DSN" tab of "ODBC Data Source Administrator".[image]

5) After I click "Test Connection" it shows "Test connection succeeded".[image]

6) When I click OK on the success message and "Connection Properties" window I come to "Data Source Properties" and see "Connection string:" is set to "Dsn=MySQLforCAD_UAT". MySQLforCAD_UAT is the DSN name I had entered in "System DSN" of "ODBC Data Source Administrator".[image]

**The problem:** When I click on "Test Connection" from this window, I get error as
[image]

**What I have tried so far:** I have tried selecting "Use connection string" instead of "Use user or system data source name:" and tried few combinations of `Dsn=MySQLforCAD_UAT;trusted_connection=Yes`

```
Dsn=MySQLforCAD_UAT;description=<DSN description>;server=<DB Server IP>;uid=<DB user id>;database=<database name>;port=3306
```

**My Questions:**

1) Why is report builder saying connection succeeded at one place and failure at the other? How can I correct this so I can connect to MySQL DB?

2) I don't have admin rights on my machine and the "System DSN" entries need admin access to be able to edit/add it. Could this be causing the problem in case if admin access is needed even to use the details I have added in "System DSN" (with help of local admin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different approach by creating a linked server. To do it, I followed instructions from [this](https://dbtricksandtips.wordpress.com/2016/04/08/connect-microsoft-report-builder-to-mysql/) link. Thank you to the author (I couldn't find a name there)